# Access global classes from within CSS module

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, css-modules

I'm working on a project that uses ReactJS and CSS modules with each react component having a corresponding SASS file.

When writing the CSS each class gets appended with the '*triple underscore random string*' e.g. `.myClass__e7G3A`

My app appends a class (top' or 'down') to the body tag depending on scroll position and I want my component to respond to this.

The problem I have is if I add either `.top` or `.down` within the CSS module then it appends the unique identifier to the end of that class too.

e.g.

**JSX:**

```
<div className={styles.main}>
  Main content goes here.
</div>
```

**Rendered HTML:**

```
<body class="top">
  <div class="main___iZy2A">
    Main content goes here.
  </div>
</body>
```

**SASS file:**

```
.top .main {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.down .main {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

**Compiled CSS:**

```
.top___Gvf3S .main___iZy2A {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.down___kpd3S .main___iZy2A {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

**Desired CSS outcome:** (`.top` and `.down` without unique identifier)

```
.top .main___iZy2A {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.down .main___iZy2A {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

I'm sure I'm just missing a simple identifier or something that could achieve this.

Hope you can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [:global](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#exceptions) on the selector:

```
:global(.top) .main___iZy2A {
  margin-top: 0;
}
:global(.down) .main___iZy2A {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Or a combination of `:global` and `:local` if you have more the one global selector:

```
:global .top .top--left :local .main___iZy2A {
  margin-top: 0;
}
:global .down .down--right :local .main___iZy2A {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured it would be something simple.

Comment: I get 'Error: composition is only allowed when selector is single :local class name not in' when attempting to do just this. Do you have any ideas where this might be coming from?

Comment: Seems like a problem in the configuration of your CSS modules. Check the css loader if you're using webpack.